# Pass Delphi image to FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I would like to show an image in FastReport.

Here is Delphi code :

```
 img_sick.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +
      'Pictures/' +  Qry_Search.FieldByName('code_personel').AsString + '.jpg');
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Put a picture object onto your report form. Let's assume it will be called `Picture1`.
2. In your Delphi code, in the method where you want to load the picture, add a line like this:

   ```
   TfrxPictureView(YourReportObject.FindObject('Picture1')).Picture.LoadFromFile(…)
   ```

   The `Picture` property is a `TPicture` and so `LoadFromFile` is the same method you are using in your example. So just supply a corresponding file name as an argument.

That is supposed to be done *prior* to running the report. If you want to load pictures *in the process* of running the report, you should perhaps try doing something similar in the report script. Maybe I would define an `OnBeforePrint` handler for the `Picture1` object, like this:

```
procedure Picture1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  TfrxPictureView(Sender).Picture.LoadFromFile(…);  // use a reference
          // to the "code_personel" column in the file name expression
          // as appropriate in the context of the report script,
          // like <Qry_Search."code_personel">, perhaps
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the "/" it is supposed to be a backslash ---> "\"

Comment: Forward slash works at API level for file name operations, as far as I know.